# Debugging RxJava zip operator that halts

Tags: java, multithreading, java-7, rx-java

Writing in Java I call zip() method that receives a few method that return an Observable<...>.

Currently I am not able to progress to the following map and this is probably due to the fact that one of the methods didn't return a value yet. (Though it seems all methods where called.)

Is there a way to debug the process and see why it is stuck?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose you have:

```
result = Observable.zip(sourceA, sourceB, sourceC)
```

Just add a `.doOnNext()` on each of the sources to log what they are emitting (or instead of `doOnNext`, subscribe to each). For instance:

```
result = Observable.zip(sourceA.doOnNext(/*logging...*/),
                        sourceB.doOnNext(/*logging...*/),
                        sourceC.doOnNext(/*logging...*/))
```

What's probably happening is that one of these sources isn't emitting at the same frequency as the others. `zip` must be used when you strictly know that all the sources emit events at the same pace/frequency. You might want to try using `combineLatest`. The difference between the two are:

- zip: the returned Observable emits the n-th 'combination' item only when all the n-th items of the sources have been emitted. See a [diagram](http://rxmarbles.com/#zip).
- combineLatest: the returned Observable emits an 'combination' item whenever any of its sources emits an item. See a [diagram](http://rxmarbles.com/#combineLatest).